# finding conjugates in group $S_n$

Tags: group-theory

Find the conjugates in $S_3$ of its subgroup <123>.

Find conjugate of $A_n$ in $S_n$.

my question:
i looking for alternative quick way to deal with this questions.thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Show that $\sigma(123)\sigma^{-1}=(\sigma(1)\sigma(2)\sigma(3))$ for any $\sigma\in S_3$. Now you know, for example, that every conjugate of $(123)$ is a cycle $(abc)$. Remember that conjugation is a homomorphism, so if you decompose any member of $S_3$ as a product of disjoint cycles (actually for $S_3$ you only have cycles), you can quickly find its conjugates using the technique above. Try to write it down in detail for any $S_n$, it will be very helpful. In my experience, conjugation is the most important group action.

Answer (score 1):

Just take $H=\{e,\sigma\}$ for any odd permutation $\sigma$. Then it is clear that $H\cap A_n=\{e\}$. To show that $HA_n=S_n$, just observe that the group $HA_n$ contains an odd permutation and all even permutations. Now let $\tau\in S_n$ be an arbitrary odd permutation. Then $\tau \sigma^{-1}$ must be even, and is therefore contained in $HA_n$. Hence $\tau=(\tau\sigma^{-1})\cdot \sigma\in HA_n$. Thus $HA_n=S_n$.

Answer (score 1):

Since subgroups of index 2 are normal, we have that all conjugates of $<(1 \;2 \;3) >$ equal itself.

Similarly, since $|S_n:A_n|=2$ we have $A_n \trianglelefteq S_n$, so all conjugates of $A_n$ in $S_n$ are $A_n$.